# Scanned Image to excel

Tags: image, converters

I have the scanned image, i tried to convert it to excel file using online tool but its not giving clear text. is there any tool/thing available to covert the image to excel?

Comment: now to your question - what exactly are you looking for ? an OCR library for programming ? Or an OCR software to use ?

Comment: I tried with OCR software,it gives a excel but its not exactly matched with image. My primary aim is that i have scanned copy of a book, now i want to load it in Database.For that i am converting this scanned files to corresponding excel file and loading data to DB from created excel.Which will be useful for this scenario, also what should i do to get the exact details as with image files.

Comment: OCR is NEVER 100% if that is your goal... why don't you load the image itself into the database ?

Comment: Hmmmmm yes,i missed out to say one thing is that After loading the data to DB , i am creating an web application where i can filter the details using search option and displaying the details to end user.

Comment: I can only tell that OCR is never 100%... even the best combination of Scanner and Software comes up with some sort of error on nearly each page... if like in your case you need real excel sheets with columns and rows I am certain that is not achievable without errors... Google has a project where they scan books (not creating Excel sheet but "mere text files") and even with their money etc. they still have errors in the scan results...

Comment: IF the documents you want to scan are all similar then it is possible to develop some software optimized specifically for these documents which should make the error rate go down alot but I wouldn't hope for "no errors at all" !

Comment: Okay. Let me know if there is any other way to achieve the same? Really Thanks for your knowledge sharing.

Comment: youe are welcome... my problem is that I don't know enogh of what you want to achieve... you say you want to scan tables contained in books... what quality do they have (new/old/used...) ? what exactly should be the result ?

Comment: Used one also i need all content from that book to DB. No need to worry about if any images in it.Sorry for late reply as big holiday here.

Comment: in what language is the content ?

Comment: English only. No need to convert it to another language

Comment: I was not asking about converting it to another language... OCR usually gets a bit better when the OCR SW knows the language to be scanned... do you want a tool which you can just use or a library which you can build your own tool with ?

Comment: Predefined tool is enough for me... I just going to convert it for a single time.

Comment: please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments above - some links to commercial OCR packages out there:

- http://www.abbyy.com/
- http://www.irislink.com/c2-1584-189/Readiris-12---OCR-Software-------Convert-your-Paper-Documents-into-Editable-Text-.aspx